# sending multiple emails with amazon ses php SDK

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

According to [Amazon's Doc's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-php.html) if I want to send multiple emails in one call I can add it simply like this

`$recipient_emails = ['recipient1@example.com','recipient2@example.com'];`

but I want to be able to send the name of the user as well so I know that the correct format for this is

`$recipient_emails = ["recipient1@example.com <recipient2@example.com>"];`

I am having a hard time finding any documentation but I am assuming I can do this to send the name with multiple emails

`$recipient_emails = ["recipient1 <recipient2@example.com>", "recipient2 <recipient2@example.com>"];`

In my code I am trying to construct the emails properly but I am not sure if my code is wrong, or I can not send the name with the emails with the example right above.

```
if ($thisisanarray == 1) {
    foreach ($to_email as $to_emails) {
        $name = $to_emails['name'];
        $username = $to_emails['username'];
        $recipient_emails_arr[] = "$name <$username>";
    }
    $recipient_emails = implode(",",$recipient_emails_arr);
    $recipient_emails = [$recipient_emails];
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: If AWS API accepts array of recipients, you don't need the last two lines from your code. Just try to pass `$recipient_emails_arr` directly. Otherwise you're creating a single string, rather than array of recipients.

Comment: @astax That was it man, thanks. Make it an answer

Answer (score 0):

If AWS API accepts array of recipients, you don't need the last two lines from your code. Just try to pass `$recipient_emails_arr` directly. Otherwise you're creating a single string, rather than array of recipients.